# Interchange of infinite product and limit

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, infinite-product

## The Problem

Let $(a_{n,m})_{n,m\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an sequence of complex numbers.
Under which conditions can I interchange product and limit?

$\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  a_{n,m}\overset{??}{=}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} a_{n,m}$

## My Idea: Uniform Convergence

Define $A_{N,m}:= \prod_{n=1}^Na_{n,m} $. Then we have

$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  a_{n,m}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{N}  a_{n,m}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}A_{N,m}$

If $a_{N,m}$  converges uniformly for either $N\to\infty$ or $m\to\infty$ , then we have

$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}A_{N,m}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}A_{N,m}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{N}  \lim_{m\to\infty} a_{n,m}= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \lim_{m\to\infty} a_{n,m}$

## The Question

**Is there any other way?**

Comment: Found in Whittaker and Watson's A Course of Modern Analysis (link below) that every convergent product converges uniformly. 

https://archive.org/details/courseofmodernan00whit